# how to grab the first x characters in a string python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the first 8 characters in the string by using the following code :

```
integer = int('789ABC', 16)

conver = format(integer, '0>24b')

x1 = conver.split()[:8]
```

but when I printing the x1,

```
 ['011110001001101010111100']
```

result didn't came out as what I wanted.

Result expecting :01111000

Comment: your code should work without the `.split()` I believe (assuming that conver is a `str`)

Answer (score 4):

`split()` is unnecessary and ends up just putting `conver` inside a list as the only element.

```
integer = int('789ABC', 16)

conver = format(integer, '0>24b')

x1 = conver[:8]
```